# Browser ignores Cache-Control

Tags: single-page-application, browser-cache, cache-control, etag

Browsers appear to ignore `cache-control` headers on resources such as images if they are being loaded within a single page app.

After reading https://madhatted.com/2013/6/16/you-do-not-understand-browser-history and tweaking their demo it seems as though browsers will happily re-retrieve  resources on the same page via ajax calls that are marked as `Content-Control: no-cache must-revalidate` however if I attempt to insert an image with all the proper `E-Tag` & `Expiry` headers and include `Content-Control: no-cache must-revalidate` then the browser *always* go to the cache from within the context of the same page (or as the aforementioned article points out if using the back button)

Consider this simplified example, where the image in question has an `Etag`, an `Expiry` in the past and `Cache-Control: must-revalidate, no-cache`. The 2nd image load after timeout still appears to avoid any HTTP request.

```
<html>
    <body>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            function addImage() {
                $('body').append($('<img>',{src:'http://localhost/must-revalidate.png'}));
            }                   
            addImage();         
            setTimeout(addImage, 3000);                 
        });
      </script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

It appears as though Chrome treats the subsequent request for the image in the same way it would if you had clicked the back button considering it also has the the same direct-to-cache behavior even when I return `Cache-Control: no-store`. It is following the spec: **If the entity is still in storage, a history mechanism SHOULD display it even if the entity has expired** even though the request isn't technically the same as a historical back button request.

Is there any way to get the browser to respect normal `Cache-Control` rules within a SPA without having to resort to always performing cache-busting and as a result *never* get the benefits of browser cache?